# Class on webdev: responsive columns break by adding margin

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am taking a Coursera web development class that was created in 2015, and I'm supposed to use what I learn. This is my homework.

Everything works, except when I apply a margin to the column property, the third column goes to the second line. Help me fix it, please.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="wclassth=device-wclassth, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Our Menu</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="heading1">
                    <span class="sectionHeader">Chicken</span>
                </div>
                <p class="section">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo excepturi, inventore rerum odit voluptas quam aliquam numquam nesciunt maxime aut quae adipisci quos corporis. Magni soluta facilis illo alias sunt?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="heading2">
                    <span class="sectionHeader">Beef</span>
                </div>
                <p class="section">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus suscipit, vel recusandae exercitationem ex pariatur, voluptates quos dolores ipsa maiores eos eveniet eum beatae modi explicabo non voluptas nobis dolorum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="heading3">
                    <span class="sectionHeader">Sushi</span>
                </div>
                <p class="section">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum autem ea velit unde deserunt sapiente totam ducimus dolor sint eum, ipsa voluptas omnis perferendis ipsam veniam eius hic. Molestiae, earum?</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: 1px solid antiquewhite;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: dimgrey;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.row {
    padding: 4px;
    height: auto;
}

.column {
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    /* margin: 2px; */
    background-color: rgb(181, 179, 179);
    width: 100%;
}

.heading1 {
    background-color: indianred;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    padding-right: -6px;
}

.heading2 {
    background-color: rgb(179, 91, 23);
    padding: 6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

.heading3 {
    background-color: rgba(53, 118, 53, 0.611);
    padding: 6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

.section {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(84, 81, 78);
    padding: 4px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 4px;
}

.sectionHeader {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: right;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 4px;
}

.container {
    padding: 4px;
    display: flex;
}


/********** Large devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-1,
    .col-lg-2,
    .col-lg-3,
    .col-lg-4,
    .col-lg-5,
    .col-lg-6,
    .col-lg-7,
    .col-lg-8,
    .col-lg-9,
    .col-lg-10,
    .col-lg-11,
    .col-lg-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


/********** Medium devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-md-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Each column has `width: 33.33%`. Simply there is no space for horizontal margins.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Changed it to 30%.

Comment: I would leave the containers to 33.33% and would add inner `div`s with margins.

Comment: One last issue: on md screen the last column doesn't go to the right. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

```css
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: 1px solid antiquewhite;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: dimgrey;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.row {
    padding: 4px;
    height: auto;
}

.column {
    /*border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);*/
    /* margin: 2px; */
    /*background-color: rgb(181, 179, 179);*/
    width: 100%;
}

.heading1 {
    background-color: indianred;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    padding-right: -6px;
}

.heading2 {
    background-color: rgb(179, 91, 23);
    padding: 6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

.heading3 {
    background-color: rgba(53, 118, 53, 0.611);
    padding: 6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

.section {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(84, 81, 78);
    padding: 4px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 4px;
}

.sectionHeader {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: right;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 4px;
}

.container {
    padding: 4px;
    display: flex;
}
.inner {
        margin: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

/********** Large devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-1,
    .col-lg-2,
    .col-lg-3,
    .col-lg-4,
    .col-lg-5,
    .col-lg-6,
    .col-lg-7,
    .col-lg-8,
    .col-lg-9,
    .col-lg-10,
    .col-lg-11,
    .col-lg-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


/********** Medium devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-md-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="heading1">
                        <span class="sectionHeader">Chicken</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="section">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo excepturi, inventore rerum odit voluptas quam aliquam numquam nesciunt maxime aut quae adipisci quos corporis. Magni soluta facilis illo alias sunt?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="heading2">
                        <span class="sectionHeader">Beef</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="section">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus suscipit, vel recusandae exercitationem ex pariatur, voluptates quos dolores ipsa maiores eos eveniet eum beatae modi explicabo non voluptas nobis dolorum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="heading3">
                        <span class="sectionHeader">Sushi</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="section">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum autem ea velit unde deserunt sapiente totam ducimus dolor sint eum, ipsa voluptas omnis perferendis ipsam veniam eius hic. Molestiae, earum?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: I have left the columns to take 33.33%. Then I added three divs with `class="inner"` in the boxes. I also commented the border and the grey background of the columns and have added them to `.inner`.